# Qual a diferença quantitativa de "um bilhão" e "mil milhões"

Tags: números

O português de Portugal e o português do Brasil têm algumas diferenças na maneira de falar.

Uma delas, que nunca fui capaz de compreender, está no valor de mil milhões usado em Portugal que me parece que não seja a mesma coisa que um bilhão usado no Brasil.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Isso não é uma questão de língua, é uma questão de **nomenclatura técnica e científica**.

A diferença é porque no Brasil se usa a escala curta, enquanto em Portugal e restantes países lusófonos se usa a escala longa.

Para informação mais detalhada, sugiro consulta do [artigo na WikiPédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalas_curta_e_longa) e da dúvida ["bilião e outros grandes números" no FLiP](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=4389).

---

Escala longa:

- 10<sup>6</sup>  = 1.000.000 = um milhão
- 10<sup>9</sup>  = 1.000.000.000 = mil milhões
- 10<sup>12</sup> = 1.000.000.000.000 = um bilião
- 10<sup>15</sup> = 1.000.000.000.000.000 = mil biliões
- 10<sup>18</sup> = 1.000.000.000.000.000.000 = um trilião
- etc

Escala curta:

- 10<sup>6</sup>  = 1.000.000 = um milhão
- 10<sup>9</sup>  = 1.000.000.000 = um bilião
- 10<sup>12</sup> = 1.000.000.000.000 = um trilião
- 10<sup>15</sup> = 1.000.000.000.000.000 = um quatrilião
- 10<sup>18</sup> = 1.000.000.000.000.000.000 = um quintilião
- etc

Answer (score 11):

Pode-se dizer que é assim:

**em inglês:**

*1,000 = a thousand

1,000,000 = a million

1,000,000,000 = a billion (9 zeros)

1,000,000,000,000 = a trillion*

**português, Brasil:**

*1.000 = um milhar

1.000.000 = um milhão

1.000.000.000 = um bilhão (9 zeros)

1.000.000.000.000 = um trilião*

**português, Portugal:**

*1.000 = um milhar

1.000.000 = um milhão

1.000.000.000 = um milhar de milhões

1.000.000.000.000 = um bilião (12 zeros)*

> Em Portugal esta regra é determinada pela norma NP-18 de 1960 (Nomenclatura dos grandes números).

**[Fonte e mais informações](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalas_curta_e_longa)**

Comment: O alemão possui uma palavra semelhante ao bilhão de portugal. A Palavra [Milliarde](https://translate.google.com/#de/pt/Milliarde) que significa um bilhão, sendo _Million_ o nosso _milhão_. Talvez seja uma característica existente em outros idiomas também.

Comment: @gmauch em Portugal não existe a palavra bilhão!! Mas em Francês: [million](www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/million) e [milliard](www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/milliard)

Comment: É sim, são duas escalas, a curta e a longa, no link que eu passei tem um gráfico mostrando quais escalas os países usam, é bem útil.


Edit: Realmente, no portugal é um milhar de milhões

Answer (score 2):

O modo usado no Brasil é bem mais prático porém vários países adotaram uma mesma norma diferente da nossa entre os quais Portugal, os países hispânicos, França, etc.  Mas mesmo assim continuam a existir diferenças do modo usado na França para o de Portugal. Por exemplo, uma música (que recomendo) do grupo de RAP L'Entourage se chama 'soixante quinze', ou seja, 'sessenta quinze' que na verdade é apenas um outro modo de se dizer 'setenta e cinco'.

Comment: Sim na França os números são ditos assim, como *quatre vingt dix neuf* que traduzido a letra é *quatro vinte dezanove* mas na realidade é noventa e nove.

Comment: `O modo usado no Brasil é bem mais prático` porquê? Eu acho a escala longa mais prática.

Comment: Por falar em "bem mais prático": um trilião vezes um bilião, quantos -liões são? Com a escala longa, é um quintilião (3+2=5); com a escala curta, é um sextilião (3+2=6). Leia-se https://www.reddit.com/r/portugal/comments/lkytwa/não_entendo_porque_é_que_usado_o_termo_bilionário/gnmv7oe/ (A nomenclatura matemática do post está toda esfedelhada, desculpem-no; mas dá para perceber.)